# Jhipster User management with JWT and microservices

Tags: oauth, jwt, microservices, jhipster

If I generate sample empty project with default JWT auth  Jhipsters seems to provide no generation for user accounts, is OAuth the only option with microservices for this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you generated only a microservice, the JWT user-management part is generated in gateway only.